# How to display/print or sort elements in a Pandas dataframe of the keywords I have searched for?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to keep track of sports equipment stocks and it consists of 3 arrays of brands, products and their prices which I have stored in a dataframe and using FuzzyWuzzy I search for a particular keyword(e.g. 'Football') and in my pandas dataframe it should only display those elements in my dataframe

So there is result array which consist of tuples of keywords I have searched for and its probability that the keyword is present in the list so I only want to display those elements in the resultant dataframe

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from pandas import DataFrame

Brands=['Nike', 'Adidas', 'Nike', 'Puma', 'UnderArmour', 'Adidas', 'Puma', 'New Balance', 'Puma']
Product=['Phantom Football Boots',
        'Football Shorts',
        'Running Shoes',
        'Evospeed Football shoes',
        'Gym Gloves',
        'Running Shoes',
        'Cap',
        'Furon Football Boots',
        'Football Size 1']
Price_USD=[200, 45, 100, 90, 30, 120,12,35,20]

stocks_df={'Brands':Brands,
           'Product':Product,
           'Price':Price_USD
            }

searchproduct=input("Enter Product Name: ")

def getSearchedProducts(searchproduct, choices, limit=5):
    res=process.extract(searchproduct, choices, limit=limit)
    return res

result=getSearchedProducts(searchproduct, Product)
df=DataFrame(stocks_df, columns=['Brands', 'Product', 'Price'])
```

so my dataframe should look something like this:

```
        Brands                  Product  Price
0         Nike   Phantom Football Boots    200
1       Adidas          Football Shorts     45
2         Nike            Running Shoes    100
3         Puma  Evospeed Football shoes     90
4  UnderArmour               Gym Gloves     30
5       Adidas            Running Shoes    120
6         Puma                      Cap     12
7  New Balance     Furon Football Boots     35
8         Puma          Football Size 1     20
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter your results to produce a list of products which have a score of X% or more (depending on how accurate you want to be) and then select only rows from the data frame which have this product.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from pandas import DataFrame

Brands=['Nike', 'Adidas', 'Nike', 'Puma', 'UnderArmour', 'Adidas', 'Puma', 'New Balance', 'Puma']
Product=['Phantom Football Boots',
        'Football Shorts',
        'Running Shoes',
        'Evospeed Football shoes',
        'Gym Gloves',
        'Running Shoes',
        'Cap',
        'Furon Football Boots',
        'Football Size 1']
Price_USD=[200, 45, 100, 90, 30, 120,12,35,20]

stocks_df={'Brands':Brands,
           'Product':Product,
           'Price':Price_USD
            }

searchproduct=input("Enter Product Name: ")

def getSearchedProducts(searchproduct, choices, limit=5):
    res=process.extract(searchproduct, choices, limit=limit)
    return res

result=getSearchedProducts(searchproduct, Product)
df=DataFrame(stocks_df, columns=['Brands', 'Product', 'Price'])

#form a list of products which has a score of 80% or more
product_result_list = [res[0] for res in result if res[1]>=80]

#create a new df of only those products from our list.
product_result_df = df[df['Product'].isin(product_result_list)]

print(product_result_df)
```

**OUTPUT: when input given as boots with an 80 or greater score**

```
Enter Product Name: boots
        Brands                 Product  Price
0         Nike  Phantom Football Boots    200
7  New Balance    Furon Football Boots     35
```